# Problems with using multiple Configurations when building a winforms application in C#

Tags: c#

I am currently attempting to use multiple build configurations which I have set up using the configuration manager in order to conditionally compile different code, producing separate versions of my program. This works absolutely fine

I have encountered a problem however in that the Assembly name and Icon I set for each version of the program is being shared across each of my configurations and changing one will change them all to the new value.

Have I missed something here? I fear this may be rather obvious.

Thank you.

Some further Info - When changing the Configuration in the Build Tab this seems to be independent for each of the various configs. However at the top of Application the Configuration Drop Down is disabled and has the value N/A on each of my projects

Comment: While it is impossible to say without more details, it sounds like you may be better off splitting your solution to produce multiple deliverables, while pushing reusable code into shared libraries. It will be easier to maintain this way. The main intent of configurations is for environment (e.g. test vs prod) as opposed to creating slight variants on an application.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I will look into this for future builds of the software. This is a supporting application for one of my embedded projects however and Ideally I'd like to get it out asap so I can move on to other work. What further information would you desire?